# Is it possible to install a chrome extension using a script

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I've a beta release chrome extension THAT I WON'T PUBLISH ON CHROME STORE.
I've several reasons to not publish it on chrome so please do not suggest solutions that require publishing it...

I've already 60 free users and 2 paid users even though my extension is unpublished, but the process of acquiring users is very complex due the fact that to install any extension that is not hosted on chrome store, google makes extremly complex so an average computer user can't do it.

considering that my user trusts me and is willing to run an .exe .bat or .ps1 on his windows computer. is there any way to install the chrome extension through an executable file?

WHAT I'VE TRIED WITHOUT SUCCESS:

- add the extension info in the `external_extensions.json` inside `default_apps` folder inside chrome folder  [nothing happens]
- add the extension info in the `external_extensions.json` inside `Extensions` folder inside chrome folder [nothing happens]
- double click extension (ERROR CRX_REQUIRED_PROOF_MISSING)
- add windows registry keys at `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Google\Chrome\Extensions\EXTENSION_ID` [nothing happens]

if you know any way to achieve that please let me know...
if someone knows the `--remote-debugging-port` flag and if it allows to do any trick

Comment: Instruct the users to install it as an unpacked extension.

Comment: @wOxxOm not a real solution, the amount of steps to use as unpacked extension is unfeasible to make it a product

Comment: You mean opening chrome://extensions page, toggling the dev switch and clicking the load button?

Comment: yes.... download a zip file, extract it, then go chrome, type something weird in the url, active dev mode, then hit load and find that folder you extracted on first step.... too many steps, too much complication, you clearly never built a product to the public to suggest this, because there would be NO USERS. im not sure if i'm clear but the goal is to have users and make money from it, is not a just a school project

Comment: Indeed this is not exactly trivial but unpacked extensions is the only method. You can simplify it by making your installer directly modify `Preferences` and `Secure preferences` files in the browser profile. The latter also requires adding a hashsum into `protection` key, algorithm for which can be seen in the source code of Chromium, I've also seen an article that explains how to do it.

Comment: Officially it is only possible on Linux. There is probably a hack for Windows, but Google would fix it if they found out and you'd have to keep finding new hacks. Your best option is to have a video showing how to add it.

Comment: Im successfully achieved install by "drag and drop" on windows, which is 10x faster/easier than unpacked load unpacked. so i'm sure anyone with real deep knowledge in the chrome code would be able to do a complete install without user intervention [a prompt asking yes or to accept something is okay]

Comment: I found a definitive solution, 100% script based install method that only requires the user to run the script... unhappily i cant grace myself the bounty points but at least i dismiss every single "it is not possible" "just tell users to load unpacked"... that is technology just, cuz you don't know it doesnt make impossible

Comment: @RafaelLima Bounties are for advertisement.  That said, just post an answer to your own question and accept that.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible to programmatically install a Chrome extension using a script. Chrome does not allow extensions to be installed silently or without user interaction for security and user privacy reasons.
Even if you try, it won't work.